# Send postmessage to ServiceWorker on AMP

Tags: javascript, service-worker, amp-html, postmessage

I am in a tricky situation. I have a service worker in my page where I can init my cache with a postmessage (so on a new version, without any change on my service worker file, I can add or remove the file from my cache).

But here my problem, I need to do the same thing on amp version on my page. I figured out how to call and register my service worker, but couldn't find a way to make my postmessage call.

Here my question: **is there any solution to make a post message call from an AMP page ?**

Comment: Is this what you are looking for - https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/9074 ?

Comment: This is near what i need but this seems to be specific to Iframe, and a service worker is call by `<amp-install-serviceworker>` tag

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by " I can add or remove the file from my cache"?

Comment: Goal is to cache assets like css and js to have faster load of page, but on new version some file may have change, but not necessary my service worker so I tell my service worker by post message current version and if it differ from version store my service worker he flush his cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if somebody as the same problematic here how I solve it : 
No more postMessage, as it's impossible to do in AMP be i store data in a json file in my server and Service worker ask the file (without any cache) to get my data